# Trying To Setup An Auto Loan ReCapture Program

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

We are trying to create an auto loan recapture program. The program goal is to target Members, who are close to paying off their current auto loan with us (within let's say 2-3 months), to open another new auto loan with us. If a Member opens another auto loan with us, we will look to reward them for their loyalty by depositing a specific amount of money (like $50) into their Savings account. The program will likely be comprised of three emails. The first email will congratulate them on being close to paying off their current auto loan and let them know if they open a new one with us that we will reward them as described above. The second email would congratulate them for opening a new auto loan with us. The third email would let them know when their loyalty reward was put into their Savings account. The focus of my request is about the best way to set this up. The process/flow for this is as follows:

1. Set up the entry source
2. Send the first email
3. Wait until a specific criteria is met (a new auto loan is opened)
4. Send the second email (so most Members likely will not receive this second email)
5. Place money into Savings account (may need to be manual for now)
6. Send third email. Initially, this seems like a job for Journey Builder.

However, once I send the targeted Members into this journey and everyone receives the first email, I now need to check to see if those Members opened a new auto loan with us (within 90 days let's say), which would create a new record entered into Salesforce FSC for these Members/Contacts. I don't know if I can access/check those new records from within the Journey for these Members at that point. If I can, I just need to better understand that part. So then I started to think maybe I need to do this is Automation Studio but I have questions of its setup there as well. On the surface, Journey Builder seems the way to go but I need further clarity on this setup so I set this program up appropriately.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This is indeed a very broad scope for a single question, and you probably will not receive a useful answer. You cover aspects of integrations, Automation Studio and Journey Builder under a single topic. You are at least on the right track, looking on your current considerations. Please consider limiting this to a single question, e.g. asking how FSC data could be accessed, providing details on what you have tried so far, to build this solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If your are integrated with Salesforce, you can create an Attribute Group in the Data Designer (Contact Builder) with your Salesforce Synchronized Data Extensions. 
You will be creating a data model here, where you define how all these tables/de's are related to one another (one-to-one ; one-to-many)

From a Journey builder decision split, you can access this attribute group (via Contact Data) and look for the field you need to check. 
You can say for path one, the field in your attributegroup needs to equal a certain value, or you can compare different fields with each other.

If you are not integrated, you can create an Automation, but I would not recommend this over integration (if you can, do it). 
You could export data from your SF instance and put it on you MC FTP. Then you can create an automation that fetches the file, imports it to a data extension.

Then you can put this data extension in an attribute group and use this in Journey Builder.

Comment: Thank you for providing your answer.  It was helpful.

Comment: @Ron remember to mark answer as accepted or upvote if helpful